# How do I solve this download manager problem (android)?

Tags: download-manager

I don't really know if this is the right place to ask this question, but can anyoane be kind and help me a little here?

My mom has a huawei smartphone. I don't know what has she pressed but now, everytime she tries to download some file from facebook like a ppt or a pdf, the download manager redirects her to ".archivetemp" folder and she can't acces the downloaded file. How can I solve this without resetting the phone?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Have you tried pressing the left arrow button left to the `.archivetemp...` text? Use it to go back to`Memorie Interna` and then select the `Downloads` folder.

Comment: @Robert the files dont show in the Downloads folder

Comment: Does this happen only on Facebook or all sources? If she downloaded the file from the Facebook app, try downloading from the browser instead? Also, mentioning the Android version might help.